# How to add class to the First tab by default?

Tags: jquery

While page loading i am showing default data for 1DAY , could you please tell me how to add class active to 1D by default ??

This is my code

```
var samplejson1day = [{
    "symbol": "1DAY"
}];
var samplejson1week = [{
    "symbol": "1WEEK"
}];

var samplejson2week = [{
    "symbol": "2WEEK"
}];

var samplejson3week = [{
    "symbol": "3WEEK"
}];


$(document).ready(function() {
    fetchTopLosersData('#1d');
    $("ul.menu li").click(function() {

    $("ul.menu li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $('.tab-container-1').find('.tab-content-1').hide().html('');
    $(tabclicked).show();
        fetchTopLosersData(tabclicked);
    });
});


function fetchTopLosersData(tabclicked) {
    var htmldatafortoploosers = '';
    htmldatafortoploosers += '<thead><th class="thheaders">Symbol</th></thead><tbody>';
    if (tabclicked === '#1d') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson1day.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson1day[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    } else if (tabclicked === '#1w') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson1week.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson1week[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    } else if (tabclicked === '#2w') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson2week.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson2week[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    } else if (tabclicked === '#3w') {
        for (var i = 0; i < samplejson3week.length; i++) {
            var symbol = samplejson3week[i].symbol;
            htmldatafortoploosers += '<tr> <td>' + symbol + '</td>';
        }
    }

    $(tabclicked).html(htmldatafortoploosers);
}
```

This is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/21/

Comment: 1D is already active in your JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `:first-child`:

```
$("ul.menu li:first-child").addClass("active");
```

Comment: @PreethiJain: also answer provided by praveen with `:first` is correct and more accurate than `:first-child`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$("ul.menu li").first().addClass("active");
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7s0ho3ju/**

Answer (score 2):

You can also try -

```
$('ul.menu li:first').addClass('active');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/21/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("ul.menu li").first().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
$('ul.menu li:first').addClass('active');
```